# Каким образом переменной $i присваивается значение (без явного присвоения)?

Tags: php, while

```
while ( $i <= 10) {
    echo $i += 1, "</br>";
}
```

Comment: ну как как. в начале на тебя будет ПЫХ ругаться в виде  предупреждений `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: i -- at line`, но в итоге посмотрит, что ты ему суешь и попробует преобразовать в соответствии с выражением. Интерпретатор всё же на такой тупой, как можно посчитать - видит, что ты даешь ему числа.

Comment: Учи матчасть - http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неустановленные переменные равны `null`, который в числовом контексте равен `0`:

```
var_dump($some); // NULL
var_dump((int) $thing); // int(0)
```

https://repl.it/I0MK/0

Answer (score 0):

$i+=1; - данное выражение тотожно $i=$i+1;
Также можна  использовать унарный ператор инкремента $i++;
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: ты не понял вопрос. он не про `$i+=1;` он про `while ( $i <= 10)`